# is it ok to develop metro-style (modern UI) app for App Store (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, cordova, appstore-approval

I am developing a phonegap application for android, ios and wp8. I am thinking to use
http://metroui.org.ua/ css library for my design.

I will assume it will be ok for wp market and android (which does not have approval process)

Would it be safe to use for ios also, or should I completely use ios feel like design pattern?

Comment: I have published iOS apps that don't follow the iOS 'rules' and they have all been approved, You should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even at the first step your application can be approved there is no guarantee. Apple could remove it later due to their rules.

I can recommend you to use Dojo. It has android, iOS, wp and blackberry themes.

http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileFileBrowser/demo.html

Answer (score -1):

hi  there  Yes metro apps  do exist  on ios  and  android  puffin browser  smart  browser  tile  weather  my dashboard dashboard  and many  more  apple  needs  metro  ui  selection  muzic   metro ui music app   i  have  found  about  200  metro  apps  on  ios  and  4  metro  apps  on mac  os  forcasting  metro  ui   will  domanate  ui  interfaces  in  the  way  future